# Possible case of a complex index and match in Excel?

Tags: excel

Assume I have the following table in Excel:

```
A B C

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

I need to lookup a number, say, 1.1, in the table that has values 1 to 9 and return the corresponding letter. Also, the number I am looking up is unlikely to be exact, so I will need to find the rounded down number. For example, if I have 1.1, I need to find 1 and return A. If the number, when rounded down, cannot be found, then it should not return anything or return "NA".

The context for this is I have a whole mortality table with many death rates. Given a random number (between 0 and 1 inclusive), I need to find this number in the mortality table and return the corresponding year of death (which is in an "earlier" row relative to the mortality rates).

How can I do this? I am thinking index & match, but I am not very good with it... Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You could use a combination of the [SWITCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e) and the [MOD](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mod-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) functions, like:  `SWITCH(randomValue,1,"A",2,"B",0,"C")`. The `randomValue` would be the result of the [ROUNDDOWN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rounddown-function-2ec94c73-241f-4b01-8c6f-17e6d7968f53) function

Comment: @Luuk Hmm... I don't think that'll work. If I understand the `SWITCH` function correctly, it is similar to `IFS` right? If randomValue = 1, then "A", else if randomValue = 2, then "B" and so on... However, this isn't "dynamic" enough, because imagine I have 20 years worth of mortality rates for 100 different ages (1 year is 1 column and 1 age is 1 row), so we have a table with 20 columns and 100 rows. The "rounded down random number" I am looking up could be anywhere in this table and I need to return the "header" of the column that this random number is found...

Comment: No, the `randomValue` should also depend on the output of the MOD function. Because you have 3 possible outputs, something like `SWITCH(MOD(ROUNDDOWN(1.1),3),1,"A",2,'B",0,"C",ERROR.TYPE(7))`

Comment: Based on Harun24HR's answer below, realized that this is similar to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339917/how-do-i-return-an-address-from-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-based-on-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=INDEX(A1:C1,,MAX(COLUMN(A2:C4)*(A2:C4<=E2)))
```

You may need array entry the formula for older version of excel. Array entry means confirm formula with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: adding `=RoundDown(E2,0)` would be better suited for the user's question:
`=INDEX(A1:C1,,MAX(COLUMN(A2:C4)*(A2:C4=RoundDown(E2,0))))`

Comment: @Gangula That would be easier. Thanks.